# notepad ++ delete everything (every character and line) before match with regex

Tags: regex, string, text, notepad++

so I have a text file as follows:

```
   stypiso6    iso6msdh   (freeUSP by CodeShop   ,sidx         è  N          ³  '      hmoof   mfhd          Ptraf   tfhd           tfdt         N     trun        p  '  C€ @  Kmdat<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><tt xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:ttm="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#metadata" xmlns:ttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#parameter" xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling" xml:lang="fr"><head><metadata><ttm:title>221968594-5e30a8b903d31</ttm:title><ttm:desc></ttm:desc><ttm:copyright></ttm:copyright></metadata><styling><style xml:id="captionStyle" tts:backgroundColor="transparent" tts:displayAlign="center" tts:extent="100% 20%" tts:fontFamily="proportionalSansSerif" tts:fontSize="30px" tts:origin="0% 75%" tts:textAlign="center" tts:textOutline="black 1px 0px" /></styling><layout><region style="captionStyle" xml:id="region2" /></layout></head><body><div region="region2"><p begin="00:00:24.366" end="00:00:28.500" region="region2" xml:id="caption4" ttm:role="caption">
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="white">Le suicide de Christine Renon,</span>
        <br></br>
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="white">directrice d&apos;Ã©cole Ã  Pantin,</span>
      </p><p begin="00:00:28.766" end="00:00:31.533" region="region2" xml:id="caption5" ttm:role="caption">
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="white">dans son Ã©cole,</span>
        <br></br>
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="white">le 23 septembre 2019,</span>
      </p></div></body></tt>
```

I want to be able to delete everything and everyline that comes before this string :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

in some of the files this string doesnt happen in the first line. like the following file :

```
   stypiso6    iso6msdh   (freeUSP by CodeShop   ,sidx         è 
»          w  '      hmoof   mfhd       [   Ptraf   tfhd           tfdt        
»     trun        p  '  € @  mdat<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><tt xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:ttm="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#metadata" xmlns:ttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#parameter" xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling" xml:lang="fr"><head><metadata><ttm:title>221968594-5e30a8b903d31</ttm:title><ttm:desc></ttm:desc><ttm:copyright></ttm:copyright></metadata><styling><style xml:id="captionStyle" tts:backgroundColor="transparent" tts:displayAlign="center" tts:extent="100% 20%" tts:fontFamily="proportionalSansSerif" tts:fontSize="30px" tts:origin="0% 75%" tts:textAlign="center" tts:textOutline="black 1px 0px" /></styling><layout><region style="captionStyle" xml:id="region2" /></layout></head><body><div region="region2"><p begin="00:15:01.700" end="00:15:04.466" region="region2" xml:id="caption217" ttm:role="caption">
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="Cyan">Un projet initiÃ© par Denis,</span>
        <br></br>
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="Cyan">juste retraitÃ©,</span>
      </p><p begin="00:15:04.733" end="00:15:07.633" region="region2" xml:id="caption218" ttm:role="caption">
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="Cyan">pas prÃªt de renoncer Ã  sa vocation</span>
        <br></br>
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="Cyan">d&apos;enseignant.</span>
      </p><p begin="00:15:08.066" end="00:15:10.466" region="region2" xml:id="caption219" ttm:role="caption">
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="white">-Ici, on est sur la voÃ»te.</span>
      </p></div></body></tt>
```

I also want every line and character before the string match to be deleted with the second pattern so both of them could be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><tt xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml" xmlns:ttm="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#metadata" xmlns:ttp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#parameter" xmlns:tts="http://www.w3.org/ns/ttml#styling" xml:lang="fr"><head><metadata><ttm:title>221968594-5e30a8b903d31</ttm:title><ttm:desc></ttm:desc><ttm:copyright></ttm:copyright></metadata><styling><style xml:id="captionStyle" tts:backgroundColor="transparent" tts:displayAlign="center" tts:extent="100% 20%" tts:fontFamily="proportionalSansSerif" tts:fontSize="30px" tts:origin="0% 75%" tts:textAlign="center" tts:textOutline="black 1px 0px" /></styling><layout><region style="captionStyle" xml:id="region2" /></layout></head><body><div region="region2"><p begin="00:00:24.366" end="00:00:28.500" region="region2" xml:id="caption4" ttm:role="caption">
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="white">Le suicide de Christine Renon,</span>
        <br></br>
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="white">directrice d&apos;Ã©cole Ã  Pantin,</span>
      </p><p begin="00:00:28.766" end="00:00:31.533" region="region2" xml:id="caption5" ttm:role="caption">
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="white">dans son Ã©cole,</span>
        <br></br>
        <span tts:textAlign="center" tts:color="white">le 23 septembre 2019,</span>
      </p></div></body></tt>
```

Comment: With the cursor at the start of the file, search for `.*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` with "regular expression" as search mode and the '. matches newline' checkbox ticked and replace by `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. As a side note, your file seems to be improperly encoded, all the accents are mangled (`Ã©cole` should be `école`, `prÃªt` `prêt`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\A.*(?=<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"\?>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **CHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\A      # beginning of file
.*      # 0 or more any character
(?=<\?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"\?>)
        # positive lookahead, make sure we have <?xml...... after
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]